# setState via ref not working inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref, react-effects

I'm trying to clear `filtered` state of a react table component using useRef viz. `ref.current.setState({...})`.
This is a snippet from my component:

```
const Customers = (props) => {
  const customerTableRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const customerTable = customerTableRef.current
    if (customerTable) {
      customerTable.setState({ ...customerTable.state, filtered: [] })
      console.log("table effect::", customerTable.state)
    }
  }, [props.selectedDealer])
```

I have a select input in the UI which is bound to `props.selectedDealer` I want to clear the filters of react table whenever user changes `props.selectedDealer`.
The react table component isn't available in the `Customers` component but at a very low level in the hierarchy:

`Customers > CustomersTable > AppTableWrapper >  AppTable > ReactTable`.

I'm passing down the `customerTableRef` to `ReactTable`. In the dev tools, I can see the ref is inflated with the component options but `customerTable.setState({ ...customerTable.state, filtered: []})` is not mutating the state of `ReactTable`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest pass customerTable to redux. After we pass it to your component by redux.
In a state variable: useState or useReducer. Updates in state variables will cause a re-render of the component.
In a ref: Equivalent to instance variables in class components. Mutating the .current property won’t cause a re-render